# Merge two files line by line in shell

Tags: shell

I have two files and I want to merge them in one but line by line

```
file1 :
1
2
3

file 2:
4
5
6

expected:
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

Have an idea to do that only with the builtins, head, cat, tail and wc ?

thank you so much

Comment: Are they only three lines long?

Comment: nope they are any size long

Comment: Why do you need to do this, is it a homework question? There is one method that is pretty apparent, with the commands you've been given. In a loop, do `head -n "$c" file | tail -n 1`, for both files, incrementing the counter `$c` each iteration. Break when `$c` is greater than the number of lines in the longest file (`wc -l < file`).

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with using paste command try this.

```
paste -d "\n" file1.txt file2.txt >> file3.txt
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't use paste

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following script. It's a simple logic but gets your result.

```
line_no=`cat file1 |wc -l`
for i in $(seq 1 $line_no)
do
awk "NR==$i" file1 >> file3
awk "NR==$i" file2 >> file3
done
```

This script assumes both your files have same length. You can change logic to get higher wc for file with higher rows and use it for line_no.

Result:

```
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Not that elegent but should do the trick.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

countA=0
while IFS= read -r lineA; do
    countA=$((countA + 1)); countB=1
    while [ $countB -le $countA ] && read -r lineB; do
        countB=$((countB + 1))
    done < file2
    echo "$lineA"
    echo "$lineB"
done < file1
```